# connect remote server using angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I have Restfull API (localhost:8180) which is having secure authentication. Using Angular JS http (or other services) I need to login into that server and get my data from localhost:8180/api/version/?1 (this is just example) Please find my code below.

```
//configure file


  app.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
      $httpProvider.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    }]);

    //setting cookie
    app.run(['$http', '$cookies', function($http, $cookies) {
  $http.defaults.headers.post['JSESSIONID'] = $cookies.JSESSIONID;
       }]);



         // My Controller

    $http({
     url:'http://localhost:8180',
     method:'POST',
     data: {
     username:'adminadmin',
     password:'passpass'
    },
 headers: {
 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "*",
 "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
 "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
 "Accept": "*/*",
 'Authorization': 'Basic adminadmin:passpass' // I guess its wrong
 }
})
.success (function(){
  console.log("Success");
  //Need to call my API here
})
.error(function(data, status, headers, config){
  console.log("Failed");
});
```

> Here I'm getting No Access-Control-Allow-Origin  and Origin null
>   error. If success I need to call localhost:8180/api/version?1 inside
>   of the success method using get or post. Here my server is
>   localhost:9596. I need to call 8180 host from 9596 host and get the
>   data into 9596 host.

Comment: Read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing

Comment: you dont need to set the origin headers via header, set  them in your API. Basically the origins refuse illegal requests, so id not use * anyway.. also you dont need authorization header like that if you send dat via POST...

Comment: `localhost` will not have the same meaning when addressed by the final user's browser ; are you sure this is what you want?

Comment: For testing purpose we take entire main server dump into 8081 host. If code was successful then we replace this 8081 host with original site. But the thing how the original site behaves in same manner 8081 also behaves.

Comment: @Maanus. In API means, in localhost:8180? That means its a server side setting? If its in server side, where I need to set in server. I'm new to angularjs. So I'm asking like this.

Comment: The headers must be set in the server, not in the client side. The error is telling you that the server can't repsond to your request

Comment: @Habib yes, depending on what kind of backend server you use, try googeling your server and setting cross domain origins

Comment: Thanks for your help guys. I'll try to contact my admin. :) Coming to the code, Is my code is good or Is there anything else to change. Can you give me some perfect example on that. Don't hesitate to ask more information. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you are getting Cross-origin Error, you need to as the server guys to add some headers sent while sending responses back to the ajax request.

Basing on Backend you need to use different approach to making this change in server:

In Java Tomcat Server: You need to configure filter mapping

Source : http://enable-cors.org/server.html